# How to get total duration of two overlapping timestamps and group by day?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have two sets of date-time stamps and require the overlap minutes between the two. There are occurrences where the end date may fall in the next day.

```
Table_A
======= 
ID   ,Start_Time _A    , End_Time_A
=======
A   ,03-02-2019 22:30   ,03-02-2019 22:43
A   ,03-02-2019 22:44   ,04-02-2019 03:41
```

```
Table_B 
======= 
ID  ,Start_Time _B      ,End_Time_B
=======
A   ,03-02-2019 22:30   ,03-02-2019 23:30
A   ,03-02-2019 23:31   ,04-02-2019 01:45
```

Require the following output -

```
ID, Date    ,Overlap Minutes
=
A   ,03-02-2019 ,42
A   ,04-02-2019 ,105
```

```
create table Overlap as
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ID, (cast([Start_time_A] as date)) as Date,
(T1.Start_time_A < T2.End_time_B    and T2.Start_time_B < T1.End_time_A 
and datediff(m, greatest(T1.Start_time_A, T2.Start_time_B), 
least(T1.End_time_A, T2.End_time_B))) as overlap,
(extract(minute from End_time_A - Start_time_A)) as a,
(extract(minute from End_time_A - Start_time_B)) as b,
(extract(minute from End_time_B -  Start_time_B)) as c,
(extract(minute from End_time_B -  Start_time_A)) as d
FROM table_A T1
INNER JOIN table_B T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID and cast([Start_time_A] as date)= 
cast([Start_time_B] as date)
where overlap='true'
order by Start_time_A;
```

Comment: Overlap first row TableA and first row TableB? This an overlap of 13 minutes (22:30 - 22:43)

Comment: Yes, for the first instance. There is an overlap for the same day in the next session of 29 minutes. Therefore, the total minutes would add up to 42 minutes

Comment: Simple overlap can be achieved by using range types (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html). The hard point is dynamically splitting the dates... maybe someone has the time to work on the second step. First one is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4120c7b13e870b10a026c04b4cd836c5